# Extending dataOuputStream in android

Tags: java, android, dataoutputstream

Hi I am using custom `dataOutputStream` as `requestStream` in android.
I found warning right after I created extended class.

```
public class RequestStream extends DataOutputStream{
/**
 * Constructs a new {@code DataOutputStream} on the {@code OutputStream}
 * {@code out}. Note that data written by this stream is not in a human
 * readable form but can be reconstructed by using a {@link DataInputStream}
 * on the resulting output.
 *
 * @param out the target stream for writing.
 */
```

And my all-set `requestStream` was like `[B@6a4fc1e` which should be complete request payload. (like above warning says it was not human readable)

And I got exception which I guess result from malformed dataOutputStream

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set request property after connection is made`

I want to know where to put `{@link DataInputStream}` in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three separate questions here.

1. Your `[B@6a4fc1e` is the result of calling `toString()`, which isn't the right thing to do with an output stream.
2. The `IllegalStateException` isn't the 'result of a malformed `DataOutputStream`'. It is the result of exactly what it says: you tried to set a request property after the connection was made, in code you haven't posted.
3. You don't put `{@link DataInputStream}` in the code. You put it in a Javadoc comment. And you already have. Unclear what you're asking.

I don't see any actual reason to extend `DataOutputStream` here.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It was not dataOutputStream problem like you said on 2. `RequestStream` works well but my attempt to print `ByteArray` in Logcat was a thing. I fixed connection part. It all works well. Thank you! I might be more cautious to figure out what error that I have.

Answer (score 0):

You rarely need to extend `DataOutputStream`.  Usually, you create one, and put data into it.

```
OutputStream os = ...;
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
dos.writeUTF("The ultimate answer is: ");
dos.writeInt(42);
```

At the other end, you create a `DataInputStream`, and extract data from it.

```
InputStream is = ...;
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
String message = dis.readUTF();
int answer = dis.readInt();
```

The extends `RequestStream` class may add additional "helper" methods to put more complex structures into the stream.  In which case, the SDK should provide another class (such as `RequestInputStream extends DataInputStream`) which contains the corresponding helpers to extract the complex structures.

---

Note:
`[B@6a4fc1e` is not the contents of the "not human readable" request stream; it is a "human readable" `String` produced by `Object#toString()`, which unless overridden, returns `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`.  In this case, the class name is `[B`, which is short for `byte[]`, and the hashcode is `6a4fc1e`.  In short, what you are seeing is the handle of the buffer itself, not the contents of the buffer.

Comment: I love your detail Note part. It really helps me to understand what was wrong in my code. Thank you !